# Prioritising scores in the VRP solution with OptaPlanner

Tags: optaplanner

I am using optaplanner to solve my VRP problem. I have several constraint providers, for example: one to enforce the capabilities and another to enforce the TW regarding the arrival time, both HARD. At the finish of the optimisation it returns a route with a negative score and when I analyse the ConstraintMach I find that it is a product of a vehicle capacity constraint.  However, I consider that in my problem it does not objective that the vehicle arrives on time (meeting TW's constraint) if it will not be able to satisfy the customer's demands.That's why I require that the constraints I have defined for the capacities (Weight and Volume) have more weight/priority than the Time Window constraint.

Question: How can I configure the solver or what should I consider to apply all the hard constraints, but make some like the capacity ones have more weight than others?

Always grateful for your suggestions and help

Answer (score 1):

I am not by far an expert on OptaPlanner but every constraint penalty (or reward) is divided into two parts if you use `penalizeConfigurable(...)` instead of `penalize(...)`. Then each constraint score will be evaluated as the `ConstraintWeight` that you declare in a ConstrainConfig file multiplied by `MatchWeight` that is how you implement the deviation from the desired result. Like the number of failed stops might be Squared turning into an exponential penalty instead of just linear.

ConstaintWeights can be reconfigured between Solutions to tweak the importance of a penalty and setting it to Zero will negate it completely. MatchWeight is an implementation detail even in my view that you tweak while you develop. At least this how I see it.

Comment: +1, do note it's always divided into two parts (`constraintWeight * matchWeight`), even with  `penalize(String constraintName, HardSoftScore constraintWeight, Function<A, int> matchWeighter)`. The difference is that matchWeight depends on the actual match (and it defaults to `1`). The constraintWeight is either hardcoded or configurable for the user in their UI through `penalizeConfigurable`). The constraintWeight also stipulates the score level (hard or soft).

Comment: matchWeight is typically used to *penalize each minute* etc. For example in conference scheduling, a 2 hour talk has conflict match weight of 120, but a half an hour talk only has a conflict match weight of 30. yet they get penalized by the exact same constraint.